# Devise/Omniauth failure: How to debug it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

After trying to "log in with Google", I'm seeing this error in the logs:

```
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
```

I can see all the data from google being sent through the URL (in the logs), including user email and name. So what could go wrong? My callbacks aren't even being executed. I only get redirected to the sign_in page of my site.

And I'm pretty sure everything is configured correctly, because this was working fine some weeks ago. I don't think I changed anything. Facebook login still works fine.

Any ideas on how to debug this failure? There is nothing else in the logs, other than those long URLs full of parameters and values. Only INFO messages. The one posted above is the only one that said something about a failure.

**UPDATE**

I added a 'failure' method to the controller

```
def failure
  render :text => params.inspect
end
```

Which stopped the redirects, and printed this:

```
{}
```

The url was this:

```
/users/auth/google/callback?_method=post&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2012-04-16T12%3A25%3A49Z_v1fNngSQJaHBQ&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.myapp.me%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback%3F_method%3Dpost&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9Urw_lYamPphTSdQ9a6DU0Ez0y5RaDDM78qPL7Xgm77nMpJiB85&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.ext5%2Cext1.value.ext5%2Cext1.type.ext8%2Cext1.value.ext8%2Cext1.type.ext2%2Cext1.value.ext2&openid.sig=2FPjo7U1e%2Fde248XpUgjQLduNAM%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawk1F5U6x_-kJnydjoww5haU41tquh1Zl2c&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawk1F5U6x_-kJnydjoww5haU41tquh1Zl2c&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.ext5=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ext1.value.ext5=Some_User&openid.ext1.type.ext8=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.ext8=some_email%40gmail.com&openid.ext1.type.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ext1.value.ext2=Some_User
```

So the thing is that all the data I need is in the URL, but devise/omniauth is not grabbing it (and apparently that's why it's calling the 'failure' method instead of my callbacks). I don't know if it should be accessible through the 'params' array, or what.

I'm also intrigued about the `?_method=post` part, because all the requests to my site are GET requests. Maybe it just means that the request done by omniauth to google was POST.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16):

To answer the original question about how you debug Omniauth, here's how to enable logging for Omniauth. Add this line to `config/initializers/devise.rb` just after you define your Omniauth strategies:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger if Rails.env.development?
```

(If you're not using Devise, just Omniauth, then add the code instead to `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`)

You'll get loads more information from Omniauth in your log file - including the full response from the callback phase.

Comment: If we want the full response from the callback phase, including headers, we can also activate the debugging in the `ouath2` gem by adding the following env variable `OAUTH_DEBUG=true`

Comment: Why should this be configured only in development?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've used rails so I'm hazy on the exact context of this answer now, but I would say the main thing is you don't want to be logging private authentication keys, ids etc in a production log
(And also you probably want to keep your prod logs not too noisy)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had this same issue and nothing I found on the net helped.  Turns out the issue was caused by how I was using Puma (practices brought over from Thin).  I was starting multiple Puma processes on the same machine (Apache reverse proxy) and it appears the call-back from Github was going to a different Puma process than the original authentication request.  **I took the Puma processes down to one and didn't have the condition again** (switched to using Puma workers: `puma -w 5`, which in turn uses processes that are managed by Puma instead of Apache round robin).  This is also why I never stumbled on the issue in development because I don't run a cluster of processes in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this as an old question and that the person who originally asked it either solved it or moved to some other solution, however, I encountered the same problem, and my quest for solution led me here.

I managed to solve it, so here it is for the next person looking for it.

It turned out to be trivial. This is what I had:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['github_key'], ENV['github_secret']
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ... devise config not related to omniauth ...
  config.omniauth :github, ENV['github_key'], ENV['github_secret']
end
```

So, I was configuring the omniauth provider in two places, and it was conflicting.

After I removed the config from omniauth.rb, the redirection request from github to `/auth/github/callback` started being processed by `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#github` instead of `#failure` as was the situation prior to the change.

So dumb error and so little info to work with...

Answer (score -2):

Did you recently upgrade your gems?  If so, it might be useful to compare omniauth and devise  versions with the previous gem versions.  It could also be an omniauth/devise dependency that changed.

I am not exactly sure what the problem is in this specific case, but if you want to dig deep in the code, then install the pry-debug gem.  It gives you the pry interface with step and next debug commands.  Add `pry.binding` in your code and it will stop execution in the server and bring up the pry interface.  For example:

```
def failure
  binding.pry
  render :text => params.inspect
end
```

Comment: You should also let people know that they will need to install the pry gem for this to work https://github.com/pry/pry